# understanding iteration in JavaScript's While loop

Tags: while-loop

Hi `< 10 would be 9 & <=10 would be 10` and I know because the toptalLaps count starts from 0 the first loop print out 10 & 11 but the conditions are still <10 <=10 so I was wondering why the first loop is printing 10 times, & the second loop is printing 11 times?

```
var totalLaps = 0;

while (totalLaps < 10) {
   console.log('Swim Another lap!');
   totalLaps += 1;
}
**10** Swim Another lap!

var totalLaps = 0;

while (totalLaps <= 10) {
   console.log('Swim Another lap!');
   totalLaps += 1;
}
**11** Swim Another lap!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you start count from 0 
so totalLaps < 10 that mean the boucle Will start from 0 to 9 so is there 10 numbers

you can set totalLaps=1 then you can find 9 number between 1 and 9

```
var totalLaps=0;
while(totalLaps < 10){
  console.log("count : "+totalLaps);
    totalLaps +=1;
}
outupt

count : 0
count : 1
count : 2
count : 3
count : 4
count : 5
count : 6
count : 7
count : 8
count : 9

total = 10 numbers from 0 to 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first while loop has the condition `totalLaps < 10`, so it will continue to run as long as `totalLaps` stays under 10.

Your second while loop has the condition `totalLaps <= 10`. This means that the loop will continue to run **as long as `totalLaps` is less than or equal to 10.** The "equal to" part of the condition is causing your loop to run one extra time, and because your laps start at zero, this means your loop runs a total of 11 times.

Check out [Wikipedia's article on Zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), it might be of use to you.